# Can teleportation save you from fall damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, teleportation

I am surprised that I wasn't able to find this question asked before, but I could see it used as quite an epic showing:

> The old lady brings your group over to the mountain base filled with sharp cliffs, jagged rocks, and a path no wider than your foot. The roaring waterfall makes the air crisp, clean, and humid as she stops by a sign adorned with a bell and a rope, looping all the way up the mountain. Turning to your group with a kind smile, the guide pulls the rope and stands in wait.
>
> "Well, aren't you going to take us to him?" one of the players exclaim, annoyed at this old hag's smugness.
>
> Just as soon as the words escaped their mouth the bell rings, causing the granny's wrinkled face to beam with a smile.*
>
> "Oh, he's on his way sonny," She says pointing her knotted cane towards the top of the waterfall.
>
> As your party looks, there is a man falling what must be 1000 ft straight into the mouth of the waterfall, finally getting swallowed by the mist below. A second later, the man you have been searching for, the man who jumped down the waterfall, emerges from behind the waterfall, dry and unscathed.

Now though this seems quite epic, the way that the guy defied death was by using a teleporting spell when he was covered in the mist to reappear on the rock behind the waterfall. From what I understand [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/do-teleportation-spells-conserve-momentum), teleportation spells do not conserve momentum, so his falling speed would go from 20d6 damage to 1ft no damage.

**Is this truly how powerful teleportation spells can be?**

Comment: Yes it does... I searched for different terms to find this kind of question and could not.... though this is not the first time the search did not show me all the possible results. What did you search to find this question?

Comment: “Teleport momentum” yielded both that question and the important linked question from that question.

Comment: Related: [Do teleportation spells conserve momentum?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108686/62294)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov odd, that's one of the things I searched for and all I got was a list of replies for the question I forgot to link (the one you just did) Now I am very confused.

Comment: Reclosed this with the conservation of momentum question. The one about misty step would be a very misleading duplicate.

Comment: @gszavae I disagree. My question was if he could ignore fall damage rather than choose to conserve momentum, The first question actually answered what I was asking perfectly.

Comment: @VictorB I'm glad you found an answer. I think that in the general case anyone who is asking "can teleportation save you from fall damage" is actually asking "do teleportation spells conserve momentum", and the misty step question relies on the other question. As such I think it's the best match as a duplicate, even if you ultimately found an answer elsewhere. But it would definitely be useful to have the other question here for reference.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130034/if-you-are-falling-can-you-misty-step-to-the-ground-to-avoid-damage