# What does Banishment do to falling momentum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, falling

A while ago, my DM let me use Banishment on myself to stop my fall from a likely fatal fall. As I was falling, I readied an action to cast Banishment on myself before I hit the ground. He let Banishment cancel the distance I had fallen, letting me fall the last 10 or so feet safely. But what would end up happening read as written? Would I have just taken the impact from hitting the ground in the Demiplane instead? Or would it actually work in the way he let me use it?

Comment: Do you mean "rules as written" where you say "read as written" in the question?

Comment: Related on [How far do you fall per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75954/how-far-do-you-fall-per-turn)

Comment: @NautArch I readied the action on my turn after I was knocked off. The fall was long enough for me to spend my turn to ready the action, as the DM ruled/told.

Comment: Related on [Do teleportation spells conserve momentum?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/do-teleportation-spells-conserve-momentum)

Comment: He gave us X feet per turn while we fell. I forget the exact quantity.

Comment: Adding that information(total height, height when you cast, falling rules) might be helpful for a full understanding of your particular case and whether or not your DM was consistent in their ruling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do teleportation spells conserve momentum?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/do-teleportation-spells-conserve-momentum)

Comment: I’ve reopened the question; relevant meta regarding the three “Primarily Opinion-based” votes: [Does "Ask the DM / GM" equate to "Primarily opinion based?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7353/321)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Banishment does not state any relation to momentum.

tl;dr D&D is not a physics engine and the demiplane is "harmless", so no damage from hitting the ground in the demiplane. The results upon returning is up to the DM.

### D&D is not a real world physics simulation.

Rules as written do not specify what happens with momentum, because it's not a real world physics simulation.  E.g. it's also [not a fluid dynamics engine](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/805200627089358848)

### Going to demiplane does not incur damage.

[Spells do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret) and [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) indicates a harmless demiplane.  Without further clarification in the rules, that adjective indicates that the target does not come to harm as a result of being banished.  The character would not take damage from hitting the ground in the demiplane.

> If the target is native to the plane of existence you're on, you banish the target to a **harmless** demiplane.

### Returning and falling *may* still incur falling damage.

The rules do not specify in what manner the target reappears.  That much is left to the determination and narration of the DM.

> If the spell ends before 1 minute has passed, the target reappears in the space it left or in the nearest unoccupied space if that space is occupied.

The [falling rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/adventuring#Falling) specify that damage is incurred at the end of the fall. This shakes out one of two ways: banishment ends the fall in the harmless demiplane, or the fall continues during the harmless demiplane.

- If the DM rules that banishment ends the falls in the harmless demiplane, no damage is incurred and the player is not prone.
- If the DM rules that the fall continues during the banishment, then the fall ends after the character reappears and damage is accrued as usual (albeit a minute after it would have otherwise).

Comment: Cool, that edit addresses my objection. One small improvement I can see would be to tie the last bit about how the DM could rule back to the question, and say something like, “Since your particular DM has ruled *X* and by RAW this is up to the DM, your DM’s ruling is right at your table.” or something like that.

Comment: Regarding "the fall continues during the banishment": It's not explicitly called out, but nothing says that the demiplane has a ground to land on.  You could fall for the entire minute in an endless sky, and that would be "harmless", too.